# Raycast alternative or optimization

Tags: unity-game-engine, raycasting

I am trying to simulate an object that emits 12k laser beam. Currently I am doing so by 12k raycast calls and getting the intersection with mesh colliders but as expected this is a very slow operation (takes upto 50ms).

I was wondering whether there is another way (or any optimizations) I could achieve the same results, putting into consideration that I have to use mesh colliders and I have them as convex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you trying to simulate an object that emits 12k laser beam ?
Depending of what you want to do : 
1. you can make a function that make e.g. 100 raycast par fram and like that in 12 frames you make all you raycast. 
2. or you can consider [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.SphereCast.html), this may be a better match than 12k racast precision.